# Removing an image using Javascript

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow

I'm wondering if how I can delete an image using jquery.

```
**<!--iView Slider Start -->**

<div id="iview">

**<!-- Slide 1 -->**
    <div data-iview:thumbnail="photos/photo1_thumb.jpg" data-iview:image="images/photo1.jpg"></div>

**<!-- Slide 2 -->**
    <div data-iview:thumbnail="photos/photo2_thumb.jpg" data-iview:image="images/photo2.jpg"></div>
</div>

**<!-- iView Slider End -->**
```

I'm using the iView responsive slideshow and I want to delete ***Slide 2***.  Do I have to add a class to it then delete it using jquery?    I want to try to delete it using jquery.  If anyone has any ideas out there, please help me.

Thank you in advance!

I've tried adding div classes to each slide and used the following script, but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".slide2").remove();
});
```

Comment: `$('#iview div').eq(1).remove()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add class names to the slides.  Just do the following:

```
$('#iview').children('div').eq(1).empty().remove();
```

[See it working!](http://jsfiddle.net/77Xaz/1/)

Comment: Works in the link you set.  Thanks!  If I wanted to get rid of the first slide, what would I have to change in the script you wrote?

Comment: To get rid of the first slide, just change `.eq(1)` to `.eq(0)`. `.eq()` just counts through the list beginning with 0.